# "doing something, I did something" or "in doing something, I did something"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Tell me please what the difference is between the following sentences.

> Trying to lift the weight, I injured my back.
>
> **In** trying to lift the weight, I injured my back.

Answer (score 1):

***In doing something*** is used for saying that as a result of doing one thing (A), you also do/did something else (B).

> In trying to lift the weight (A), I injured my back (B).
>
> In passing my drivers test (A), I am now licensed (B).
>
> etc...

Other than that, the sentences have the exact same meaning. They're just worded differently.

Comment: Yes, the one with "in" + -ing verb is slightly more specific. It expresses a causal relationship between A and B. B is often a result that the protagonist cannot control. It would not be appropriate to add "in" to "Sweating from the heat, I wiped my face" because wiping one's face is volitional. But "In sweating from the heat, I became dehydrated" is OK.